# How to write proper std::initializer_list constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, initializer-list

Consider following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct C {
    std::vector<int> a;
    std::string b;
    bool c;
};

void printC(const C &c) {
    // ...
}

int main() {
    printC({
        { 1, 2, 3 },
        "ehlo",
        false
    });
}
```

This works, because compiler can generate proper constructor for me. But if I change struct C to this:

```
struct C {
    std::vector<int> a;
    std::string b;
    bool c;

    C() {
        c = false;
    }
};
```

The printC call stops working because compiler stops generating appropriate constructor. I've tried to write myself a constructor using std::initializer_list but failed.

So the question is - How to write constructor that will make the above code compile and work again?

Comment: Don't forget to `#include <string>`!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I've tried to write myself a constructor using std::initializer_list but failed.

You don't need one. You just need a c'tor taking a vector, string and boolean:

```
C(std::vector<int> a, std::string b, bool c) 
  : a(std::move(a))
  , b(std::move(b))
  , c(c) {
}
```

Your code should now be well-formed again. Though now it incurs two move operations, while the original aggregate version could have initialized the elements of your object directly. It's something worth considering.

Comment: Eh, that's gonna get inlined. If you the code is *really really* performance-sensitive, you might want to look at the generated assembly to confirm, but in general, it is *not* something I would consider.

Comment: Context where I came accross this problem fortunately doesn't care about performance much. This is the correct answer, I originally had struct S nested in unordered map and didn't realize that not everything is initializer list.

Comment: @doomista - You aren't gonna see a performance hit even with the moves. Vector and string are fairly optimized. But this applies to all user defined types, where a move can be arbitrarily expansive or cheap. It's something worth keeping in mind.

Answer (score 5):

Worth noting that in C++14 and later you can just use a default member initializer:

```
struct C {
    std::vector<int> a;
    std::string b;
    bool c = false;
};
```

Also, aggregate initialization generates no constructors. It bypasses them entirely.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an instance of a `std::initializer_list<int>` like this:

```
#include <initializer_list>

struct C {
    /* Data members... */

    C(std::initializer_list<int> vecData, std::string str, bool flag) :
        a{vecData}, b{std::move(str)}, c{flag} {}
};
```